# Checkboxes don't work in spilt view in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have checkboxes in spilt view of jQuery mobile and I can not get the to be selected. However, If I take the page off spilt view and do it by itself the checkboxes work they are selectable.

http://70.155.21.88:8888/dev/new_mobile/ipad/experiments/splitview/index.html

You can see what I am talking about in the above link. I have no idea what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem just by using the code that is found on the JQuery Mobile Page and then customizing it. Try doing the same:

```
        <div  data-role="fieldcontain" >
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <legend>Choose as many snacks as you'd like:</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" />
                <label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" />
                <label for="checkbox-2a">Doritos</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a" class="custom" />
                <label for="checkbox-3a">Fritos</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```